# set-cookie header not working

Tags: cookies, web, go

I'm developing a small site w/ Go and I'm trying to set a cookie from my server.

I'm running the server on localhost, with 127.0.0.1 aliased to `subdomain-dev.domain.com` on port `5080`.

My When I receive the response for my `POST` to `subdomain-dev.domain.com:5080/login` I can *see* the `set-cookie` header.  The response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: /
Set-Cookie: myappcookie=encryptedvalue==; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 13 Sep 2013 21:12:12 UTC; Max-Age=900; HttpOnly; Secure
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 20:57:12 GMT
```

Why isn't Chrome or Firefox recording this?  In Chrome it doesn't show up in the Resources tab.  In FF I can't see it either.  And in neither do I see it in future Request headers.

Comment: BTW, why don’t you use `SetCookie` in `net/http` and write it on your own?

Comment: I am using `SetCookie` (or rather, gorilla/sessions is).  It wasn't an issue w/ how to set it, it was an issue of why chrome was igonring it. ;) Thanks for the input!

Comment: Besides the other great comments of things to investigate, I recently found that if you are using `fetch` to send the request, chrome < 68 had default behavior to drop all cookies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981488/cookie-in-chrome-68-not-accepted

Answer (score 76, accepted):

See that `Secure` string in the cookie?

Yeah, me too. But only after a few hours.

Make sure you're accessing your site by SSL (https:// at the beginning of the URL) if you've got the Secure flag set.

If you're developing locally and don't have a cert, make sure you skip that option.

Comment: This is not the answer, you should not be able to see the cookie httpOnly from chrome or firefox ..

Comment: @julestruong It was definitely the answer...since I answered my own question. I wasn't trying to access from Javascript; just trying to set the cookie. This was years ago, but it was just a session cookie.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I had to add this to my response:

```
access-control-expose-headers: Set-Cookie
```

I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) that my Set-Cookie header was not accessible to my client unless I added it to the exposed-header header.
Hope this can help someone!

Comment: For me still is not setting the cookie with set-cookie response header.
I have found it is forbidden response header: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name

Comment: But mine is http cookie, will I be able to fetch that cookie as well?

Comment: this is only relevant to cors requests

Comment: @PiotrŚródka Could you please elaborate what you meant about `Set-Cookie` being a forbidden response header if it is the header that all servers and browsers use to set cookies?

Answer (score 12):

Found related github issue [response cookies not being sent](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/386#issuecomment-243229388) that helped. 
In my case I am running react app under https (with mkcert tool) and making cross origin fetch request and get response. Cookies of the response is not set until I

1. specify `credentials: 'include'` for fetch request
   example [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

```js
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

2. Specify these response headers from server

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has value of the url of my react app.

3. add these attributes of **Set-Cookie** Header  `Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None` [using http cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: You don't need to add SameSite=None for it to work IMO. It exposes your website to CSRF attacks

Answer (score 1):

For others who have encountered this issue, the set of things I needed to do in order to get my cookie (I happen to be using fastapi-users on the backend and js fetch api on the frontend):

- change my cors configuration so that the set of headers was not "*" but fully specified (I pulled from the [standard request fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Standard_request_fields))
- add `cookie_samesite="none"` to my cookie transport in my backend configuration
- add `credentials: 'include'` to my request in the fetch api

Comment: It appears you can also do this in Starlette exposed set_cookie if you prefer this over using CookieTransport... https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie

Answer (score 0):

flask, flask_jwt_extended

My issue was, that I had a function (`@Blueprint.after_app_request` - that was run right before the response was sent back to client) that set a header on the response to refresh the cookie.

So my logout function added the header to expire the cookie, and the refreshing function refreshed my cookie.

So the response had following headers:

1. Expire the cookie.
2. Refresh the cookie.

Maybe this will help somone one day.

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case anybody new to web development, still struggling, with cookies not working. (as I was).

In order to get cookies working, you need to configure your cors settings on the server side and it seems like just "origin: *" wont do it.

I had to set my origin and then set my credentials to true on the server side.
Example of how to do it if your using node- `app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5173", credentials: true }));`

Also on the frontend side when fetching data you need to make sure to set withCredentials to true. This options will include cookies and authentication headers in your XHR request.

example of doing it in axios- `const response = await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });`

Hope this may help someone struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cookies were set correctly but I was reloading the page immediately after a successful login:

`window.location.reload();`

When I removed that line I saw that cookies were actually set, I could see them in dev tools. Now I am trying to understand why the cookies are cleared upon page reload on my website (I am testing under https://127.0.0.1:3000)...

Answer (score 0):

this will solve the problem okk

cookies extra option to be

secure: true,
httpOnly: true,
sameSite: "None",
path: "/",

then

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:5173", credentials: true }));
```

and while requesting

```
const res = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/product",
        form,
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
```