# Cookie in Chrome <= 68 not accepted

Tags: express, google-chrome, nginx, cookies

I am actually testing a react application with an nginx and express backend, with cookie based authentication. During tests with older browsers (using browserstack and lamdatest) I identified a very strange cookie issue. For chrome browsers older than version 68 Cookies are not set. The cookie is shown in the cookie tab within the development tools, but not for the site (and is also not sent in subsequent requests). Starting with Chrome 68 everything works as expected.

Thats how the cookie is created

```
res.header('Set-Cookie', "test=value; Path=/; Domain=minaxus.at; Max-Age=100000; SameSite=Strict;");
```

Another application of mine (Angular with php/apache) sets the cookie very similar and works fine.

A difference I could identifiy is within upper/lower case, but as far as I know this should not be an issue. I did not find yet, wqhere to change this lower case conversion in node/express/nginx.

I know Chrome 67 is quite old, but for some older mac operating (eg. mavericks) systems there is only Chrome 67 available.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Dietmar

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome 68, the fetch api accepts (and sends) cookies per default. For older Browsers, the option "credentials" has to be set to include.

```
const options: RequestInit = {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

const response = await fetch(host + endpoint, options);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'm surprised this change isn't noted anywhere...